# При посещении сайта надо, чтобы именно у посещении с android устройства производилось конкретное действие

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Я не знаю что гуглить). Вот пришел посетитель на сайт, и если у него андроид, то появляется уведомление мол у нас есть приложение вот ссылка.  Вот как сделать, чтобы он в принципе реагировал так на ОС?

Comment: https://php.ru/manual/function.php-uname.html

Comment: php этой командой определяет на какой системе он сам исполняется - то есть система сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут посмотрите.
Браузер клиента хранит такую инфу.
https://proweb63.ru/help/js/js-detect-platform

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются на данном ресурсе. Лучше поместите код из приведенного источника.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью PHP можно реализовать так:

```php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(stripos($agent, 'android') !== false)
{
    echo "your message";
}
```

Comment: Зачем `strtolower` если все равно используется регистронезависимое сравнение?